# How is Django running on Windows machine?

Tags: python, django, web-applications, server, hosting

I have a machine that I inheritied at work.  The previous user setup a small Python/Django web app that we all have access to within our LAN.  However, I don't understand how it is running.  If I reboot the machine the web app stays accessible as "IP_ADDRESS:8000/myapp", but I don't see a scheduled Windows Task that calls manage.py and I don't see any obvious services running that would be hosting it.  Is there any way I can find this out?

Comment: BTW, it's running Windows 7.

Comment: Look for the Apache httpd service. One option is that it is using mod_wsgi with it. Alternatively could be using MS IIS with a FASTCGI/WSGI adapter.

Comment: Well, I can't find any service with "Apache" in the name.  And IIS is not installed.  I'll look into wsgi.  Thanks.

Comment: In the web app's folder I only found one reference to "wsgi".  A file containing this:

`import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()`

Comment: Might be IIS Express?  Running "inetmgr" produces an error, so I assume that means regular IIS is not installed.  But there are "IIS" and "IIS Express" folders in the "Program Files" folder.

Comment: Apache service may not be called 'apache', but use 'httpd' as name.